# Resteasy jaxrs using io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx

Tags: reactive-programming, vert.x

I am building a Vertx application with a Jaxrs webservice interface.

I am using the following dependency in my app:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
>         <artifactId>resteasy-vertx</artifactId>
>         <version>4.0.0.Beta8</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

I noticed that Resteasy uses vertx from io.vertx.core.Vertx package.  However, I need to use a Vertx from package io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx.

The following api in Resteasy requires io.vertx.core.Vertx for the "vertx" argument:

```
new VertxRequestHandler(vertx, vertxResteasyDeployment)
```

Is there a way to pass in io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx object instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an rxified Vertx instance, you can retrieve the underlying core instance with `getDelegate()`.